# txml question help

Tags: geometry

In the coordinate plane, the vertices of a quadrilateral are (-4,-2), (8,5), (6,8), and (-1,6). What are the coordinates of the point in the plane for which the sum of the distances from this point to the vertices of the quadrilateral are minimum?

What would be the best way to tackle this problem and would it involve am-gm?

Comment: is that not the steiner point?

Comment: Looking at various texts, I doubt the test makers would incoporate a topic of such complexity into an AMC 12 level test.